# How to make an alert when element is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have really simple problem. I want to make a script that appears alert when I click on an image.

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" \>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lightbox.js" type="text/javascript" \>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
$("img").click(function() {
  alert("dadadad");
});
```

I'm new to Javascript, so all tips will be helpful

Comment: Get rid of that second `l` in `alert`.

Comment: A general hint: open your browsers console (typically F12), that is where you can see errors in your javascript code...

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: What @MattCremeens said. You should also use your browser's console to do some debugging.

Comment: Also, change the `\>` to `/>`.

Comment: still not working. and i dont know how debugger will help me if i dont know how to use it

Comment: So you never started using a tool, since obviously you never know in advance how to use one? Hm....

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that any jQuery code that you write is defined within a "document-ready" block as seen below and that it occurs *after* your jQuery reference:

```
<img class="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></img>
<script>
   // This will ensure that jQuery has been loaded before it is used
   $(function(){
        $("img").click(function() {
               alert("dadadad");
        });
   });
</script>
```

**A Pure Javascript Approach**

It's worth noting that you don't *need* jQuery for this as the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function would suffice:

```
<script>
    // Select all of your images
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
       // Wire up a click event listener for each of them
       images[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         alert('foo');
       });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its working! thanks. but could you tell my why is this code not working outside of function?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the use of the `$(function(){ ... })` will ensure that jQuery has been loaded prior to it being used. Without this block, when the `$` symbol is encountered, it won't know what that is and thus won't ever create your event listener and thus your code won't work. I added a pure JS implementation example if you didn't want to involve jQuery as well.